# Cannot Serialize a class already Serialized?

Tags: java, serialization

See the snipper below

```
    USPresident usPresident = new USPresident(56);
    try (ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new
    FileOutputStream("/home/nikhil/dev/USPresident.data"))){
    oos.writeObject(usPresident);
    usPresident.setTerm(57);
    oos.writeObject(usPresident);
    System.out.println("Serialized");
    }
```

Created an Instance of President with term as 56. 
Serialized it.
Reset the term to 57
Serialized it again

But, when I deserialize the object, it still has the term as 56 (and not 57!)

I see this explanation given i book,

> Yes, it will print 56 even though you changed the term using its
>   setter to 57 and serialized again. This happens due to
>   serialVersionUID, which is checked by the JVM at the time of
>   serialization. If a class is already serialized and you try to
>   serialize it again, the JVM will not serialize it.

But, as of my understanding, serialVersionUID is used to check if the Class object matches with the serialized object during deserialization. Also, the serialVersionUID is used as an identifier of the Object signature and not the state.

Don't understand what is happening here. Can someone explain this behavior?

Had a look into the implementation of ObjectOutputStream and this is how writeObjet is implemented

```
public final void writeObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if (enableOverride) {
        writeObjectOverride(obj);
        return;
    }
    try {
        writeObject0(obj, false);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        if (depth == 0) {
            writeFatalException(ex);
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

see the boolean *enableOverride* . This has to be true to write 'modified' object. However, this can be set to true, only if the use does subclass the ObjectOutputStream. See the protected constructor below,

```
protected ObjectOutputStream() throws IOException, SecurityException {
    SecurityManager sm = System.getSecurityManager();
    if (sm != null) {
        sm.checkPermission(SUBCLASS_IMPLEMENTATION_PERMISSION);
    }
    bout = null;
    handles = null;
    subs = null;
    enableOverride = true;
    debugInfoStack = null;
}
```

Why such a strange behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your book is wrong, and the `serialVersionUID`, which is static, is for dealing with different versions of the class itself.

The idea of serialization is to take a live object (the one pointed to by `usPresident`) and save all its state into some external form (bytes, XML, JSON). You can then turn that state back into a copy of the object. It's like saving a file in your word processor.

However, if you modify the object after serializing it, there's no connection. You've already written bytes out to disk, and they won't change because you call methods on the object. When you recreate the object from those bytes, it will have the same values it did when you saved it. If you forget to save your changes to your word-processing document, the file on disk still has the old contents.

In your case, you're running into an quirk in Java serialization because you're writing the same object multiple times into the same `ObjectOutputStream`. So that you can serialize complex object relationships, Java serialization only saves an object once and then links back to it when it's saved again. Close and reopen the stream, and you should see updated values.

Comment: I undestand. But, what if I modify the object after serialization and then serialize it again (like in the question). Why does it not write again to the disk?

Comment: @NikhilKuriakose Ah, I see. The reason is that when you write *the same object* to a single `ObjectOutputStream` multiple times, Java only saves one copy and then just links back to it.

Comment: chrylis.. I get that.. This was my question. What is the reason behind such a behaviour? Have appended more details to the question..

Comment: @NikhilKuriakose Are you asking why Java serialization only saves one copy of an object's contents? It's primarily to deal with circular references.

Comment: No.. i mean to ask, why is it not letting me overwrite the previous content. And why is ObjectOutputStream implemented in such a queer way?

Comment: @NikhilKuriakose If the `ObjectOutputStream` is connected to a network socket, such as in RMI, how do you expect to get those bytes back?

Answer (score 3):

> Why such a strange behavior?

It is to preserve object identity.

Put the same object into a Collection three times, serialize it, deserialize it, and you still get the same object back three times (not just three different objects with equivalent state). Without this, you could also not serialize a self-referential object graph (it would run into an endless loop).

> Also, the serialVersionUID is used as an identifier of the Object signature and not the state.

That's right. Your book is wrong on this count. `serialVersionUID` has nothing to do with what happens here.

> But, what confuses me is when the second time, 'writeObject' is called. I expect it to overwrite the data written to disk.

That cannot be done in any efficient manner.

You cannot go back in the stream (maybe already sent over the network, for example), and the serializer has no way to detect if an object has changed (and doing this unconditionally would again kill the ability to work with cyclical object graphs).

FWIW, while you cannot overwrite the first object, you can force the stream to write a new copy for the second time by calling [`oos.reset()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html#reset%28%29) before you write it. Note that this however, will write second copies of all objects you have in there, including things like Strings.

Comment: Understood. I am not expecting multiple objects while deserializing it. But, what confuses me is when the second time, 'writeObject' is called. I expect it to overwrite the data written to disk. This is what we would expect from a Map implementation too. If there already exists data, overwrite it.

Answer (score 2):

In order to re-write the object (write a second copy of the object) with the updated state into the stream you'll have to `reset()` the stream in order to remove the copy of the object from the set of "known objects". It can be done like this:

```
...
usPresident.setTerm(57);
oos.reset();  // <-- this guy!
oos.writeObject(usPresident);
```

Further, when you're reading the objects back - you'll have to read **two** objects, the first one that was saved (with state of `term == 56`) and the second (with state of `term == 57`):

```
ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(
     new FileInputStream("/home/nikhil/dev/USPresident.data"));
usPresident = (USPresident)in.readObject();
System.out.println("usPresident.getTerm() = " +usPresident.getTerm()); // prints 56

usPresident = (USPresident)in.readObject();
System.out.println("usPresident.getTerm() = " +usPresident.getTerm()); // prints 57
```